# Convert multiple lines to single line and store in a variable in python

Tags: python

> In a mail, below lines are there. These lines are to be converted to
>   single line based on "List Num" . For printing, the below code is
>   working. I would like to store it in a variable to further analysis.

```
mail = mailbody.splitlines()
nmail = ""
lnflg = "yes"
for line in mail:
    if re.findall(r'List Num:\s*([A-Z][0-9]{5}[A-Z]*)', line) != []:
        lnflg = "no"
        print "\n"
    if lnflg == "no":
        print line.rstrip(os.linesep),
    else:
        print line
```

Below code is not working, if I print using for loop

```
mail = mailbody.splitlines()
nmail = ""
lnflg = "yes"
for line in mail:
    if re.findall(r'List Num:\s*([A-Z][0-9]{5}[A-Z]*)', line) != []:
        lnflg = "no"
        #print "\n"
        nmail = nmail + "\n"
    if lnflg == "no":
        #print line.rstrip(os.linesep),
        nmail = nmail + line.rstrip(os.linesep)
    else:
        nmail = nmail + line
```

## For loop to print the nmail

```
    for ln in nmail:
    print ln
```

List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI

Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1

Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX

Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ

Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)

Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG

Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087

```
        BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.
```

List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI

Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1

Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX

Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ

Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)

Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG

Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087

```
        BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.
```

Expected output in a variable:

List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1 Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD    Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E) Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087             BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.

List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1 Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD    Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E) Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087             BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the mistake here is to have a `comma`(,) at the end of the line.

```
nmail = nmail + line.rstrip(os.linesep),
```

If you have a tuple type, you can only add another item to it if it is also a tuple. You start off with a string, which means you can only add similar types to it.

Here's a sample for tuples which shows the problem:

```
>>> a = (1,)
>>> a+2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Comment: True.. It is working.. However, If I try to print nmail using for loop, it is not printing as expected.     "for ln in nmail:
        print ln"

Comment: I suggest you to close this issue and open another one as the initial problem has been sorted and it will give others a chance to look at your question as well